# Как скопировать файлы из одной папки в другую?

Tags: java

Добрый день, завис на методе copy не могу понять как им воспользоваться ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {       
    ArrayList<String> selectFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    File folder = new File("путь");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (File f : listOfFiles) {
        selectFiles.add(f + "");
    }    

    File source = new File(" " + selectFiles);// ПОЛУЧАЮ СПИСОК ФАЙЛОВ ПРИСВАИВАЮ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ С ФАЙЛАМИ 
    File dest = new File("путь");// ПРОПИСЫВАЮ ПУТЬ КУДА КОПИРОВАТЬ             
    copy(source, dest);     
}

public static void copy(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
}
```

Но так не работает выдаёт ошибку

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 3: с перечеслением всех файлов в папке

.

Comment: метод copy у класса Files может копировать только файлы, не директории. Вам надо скопировать именно директорию со всеми внутренними файлами в другую директорию?

Comment: По одному файлу пробовали? Т.е. получать не папку, а именно список файлов?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov  Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @Chubatiy Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: вы очень странно формируете имя файла source. ArrayList преобразуете к String.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov а как надо ?

Comment: Добавил ответ, попробуйте

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас неправильно формируется имя файла для `source`.

Код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
private static void copyDir(String sourceDirName, String targetSourceDir) throws IOException {
    File folder = new File(sourceDirName);

    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    Path destDir = Paths.get(targetSourceDir);
    if (listOfFiles != null) 
        for (File file : listOfFiles)
            Files.copy(file.toPath(), destDir.resolve(file.getName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
for (File f : listOfFiles) {
    Files.copy(f.toPath(), new File("путь" + File.separator + f.getName()).toPath());
}
```

Comment: При такой конструкции  Files.copy(f, new File("путь" + File.separator + f.getName())); copy подчёркивает красным.

Comment: Исправил ответ. Пробуйте

Comment: Спасибо за совет с предыдущим ответом всё заработало.